# Find the solution set for $\theta$ from the equation: $\tan(2\theta) \tan(\theta) =1$

Tags: trigonometry

I need to solve this without breaking down $\tan(2\theta)$. I have got this solution. But the answer in the book is different.

$$ \begin{align*}
\tan(2\theta) &= \cot(\theta) \\
\tan(2\theta) &= \tan\left( \frac{\pi}{2} - \theta \right) \\
2 \theta &= n \pi +\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta \\
3 \theta &= \left(n + \frac{1}{2} \right) \pi \\
\theta &= \frac{\pi}{3} \left( n + \frac{1}{2} \right)
\end{align*}$$

Hence, $$ \theta = \pi (\frac{2n + 1}{6})$$

Comment: No images. Please use Mathjax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first step, you must include the condition that $\tan \theta \ne 0$, since dividing by $\tan \theta$ is only permitted if $\tan \theta \ne 0$.  Moreover, we can see that the LHS is zero whenever $2\theta$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$; this means we must exclude any solutions for which $\theta = k\pi/2$ for some integer $k$.

The rest of your solution is valid:  we obtain the set $$\theta = \frac{(2k+1)\pi}{6}, \quad k \in \mathbb Z,$$ but eliminating the aforementioned extraneous solutions gives instead $$\theta = \frac{(6k \pm 1)\pi}{6}, \quad k \in \mathbb Z.$$

Comment: How to eliminate the solution set ${\frac{n\pi}{2}}$ from the set $ { \pi (\frac{2n + 1}{6}) }$

Comment: @J9865 One way is to make a list of several numbers of the form $\frac{2n + 1}{6}\pi$ in sequence (say for $n=0,1,2,3,4,5,6$). Then cross out the ones that are extraneous. See if you can recognize a repeatable pattern in the numbers that remain. If you aren't sure how to extend the pattern, list more numbers and cross out the extraneous ones until you see a pattern.

Comment: Ok I've got it. After eliminating, we get the solution set {$\frac{\pi}{6}, \frac{5\pi}{6},  \frac{7\pi}{6},  \frac{11\pi}{6}, \frac{13\pi}{6}$......}. This can be written as {$\frac{6k \pm 1}{6}: k \in \mathbb{Z} $}

Comment: @David K is there any other method to eliminate a set from another set?